# I am new to node js and mongodb, and I want to apply it in a project with the Google Maps API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps

I am doing a project where latitude and longitude are stored in a NoSQL database (MongoDb), I want the Google Maps API to take only those 2 values of all the documents in the bd and add them to the map with their marker respectively.

```
<script>

const CASA = 18.177339;
const UNI = 18.074612;

function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
      center: {lat: 18.1778670, lng: -93.1042920}
  });

  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  // Textos
  var infoCasa = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  infoCasa.setContent('<b> ¡Hola! Aqui es mi casa  </b>');

  var infoUni = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  infoUni.setContent('<b> Y esta es mi uni =)  </b>');

  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  var markers = locations.map(function (location, i) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
    });

    if (locations[i].lat == CASA) {
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoCasa.open(map, marker);
      });
    } else if (locations[i].lat == UNI) {
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoUni.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    return marker;
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
    { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
}
var locations = [

  { lat: CASA, lng: -93.063082 },
  { lat: UNI, lng: -93.167336 }, 

]
  </script>
  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_Key&callback=initMap">
  </script>
  <script>
</script>
```

I only have the code that provides the Google Maps API documentation.

My database is like this:
[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XssG9.png)

What I need is to select the latitude and longitude of all the collections in the database and each category that I have (agros, palm, etc.) and that the Google Maps API add it to the map

Comment: can you please add the relevent code?

Comment: I will modify it to add the code